# cpusets compiled in kernel but not visible when running

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Device: radxa ( 4-core ARM ) the official kernel from radxa is used with the ubuntu 14.04 rootfs : https://github.com/radxa/linux-rockchip.git. As cpusets where not enabled in def_config, i enabled them in menuconfig. Afterwards i booted the board successfully. No errors when compiling nor when running.

If i check for cpuset support in the cgroups, there no available.

```
root@radxa$ cat /proc/cgroups 
#subsys_name    hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
debug   0   1   1
cpu 0   1   1
cpuacct 0   1   1
memory  0   1   1
freezer 0   1   1
```

Then i checked dmesg, normally on a  computer where cpusets work i get the following.

```
zilleplus@ThinkPad:~$ dmesg | grep cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

But on the Radxa board i get nothing

```
root@radxa$ dmesg | grep cpuset
... empty line ...
```

When i try to mount a cpuset anyway i get the following error:

```
root@radxa:~# mount -t cgroup -ocpuset cpuset /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
mount: special device cpuset does not exist
```

How do i continue from here? cpusets where selected in the menu when compiling the kernel without errors.

Comment: *"cpusets where selected in the menu when compiling the kernel"* -- That only builds the driver(s) into the kernel binary (or as loadable modules).  You still have to specify device & driver configuration.  The old ARM way of configuration was through a board file; the new ARM way is with a Device Tree.  The kernel will only probe and initialize a device driver that has been specified in the (board or DT) configuration.